# PING multiple Arguments with BASH script

Tags: linux, bash, networking

I try to do a simple script with BASH that try to ping each Arguments($1 $2 $3...etc). From now, I'm able to ping a single argument and receive the good answer but it not working properly with multiple arguments entered; like this (./Script.sh Arg1 Arg2....). Plus, the script work for a single Arguments entry but it keeps telling me that their is an error link to my line 6 just before giving the echo link to the condition.

```
#!/bin/bash


PING=`ping -c 1 "$@" | grep bytes | wc -l` 

for ip in "$@"; do "${PING}" ;
    if [[ "$PING" -gt 1 ]];then 
        echo "L'address ${ip} ping"
    else
        echo "L'adresse ${ip} ne ping pas"
    fi
done
```

and the output is :

```
./bash3.sh: line 6: 2: command not found
L'address IP ping
```

if I add more then one address before executing it always pass by the else which is "Address unreachable"

Comment: `PING` contains the output of the `wc -l` command. Why are you trying to execute that? It looks like you want a function.

Comment: Pinging a long list of hosts with `ping` sequentially can take a very long time, you should add a timeout with the `-t` option of BSD/GNU `ping`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `PING` to the output of the `ping -c 1 "$@" | grep bytes | wc -l` command when the script starts. You're not setting it to the command line so that you can execute it during the loop.

Use a function, not a variable.

You can also use the `-c` option to `grep` to return the count of matches, rather than piping to `wc -l`

```
ping_count() {
    ping -c 1 "$@" | grep -c bytes
}

for ip in "$@"; do
    if [[ $(ping_count "$ip") -gt 1 ]];
    then echo "L'address $ip ping"
    else echo "L'adresse $ip ne ping pas"
    fi
done
```

Also, `ping` sets its exit status based on whether it got a response. So instead of counting matching lines, just test the result of `ping`.

```
for ip in "$@"; do
    if ping -c 1 -q "$ip"
    then echo "L'address $ip ping"
    else echo "L'adresse $ip ne ping pas"
    fi
done
```

Comment: You right turning my ping in a function fix my problem ! Thanks Barmar, the only things is echo still needed in the else option if you want to fix the answer you gave. I will give you the check mark !

Comment: Why wouldn't echo be needed in the `else`? Don't you want to know which IPs don't ping?

Comment: Yes it is in fact needed but in your answer you just enter else "L'adresse $ip ne ping pas" and BASH see it as a 

./bash3.sh: line 11: L'adresse 192.168.99.10 ne ping pas: command not found

Comment: oh of course, that was just a typo. I thought you were asking if the `else` needed to echo.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for input in "$@" 

    do  
        ping=$(ping -c 1 $@ | grep bytes | wc -l)
        if [ $ping -gt 1 ];  then 
            echo "L'address IP ping"
        else
            echo "L'adresse IP ne ping pas"
        fi  
    done
```

Comment: You should use `$input` in the `ping` command, not `$@`